# Prolog factorial non-recursive

Tags: prolog, factorial

How would you convert this to non-recursive. This code puts out the factorial of N.

```
 fakultaet(0, 1). 
 fakultaet(N, F) :- 
     N > 0, 
     N1 is N – 1, 
     fakultaet(N1, F1), 
     F is N * F1.
```

Comment: I'm assuming that by "Faculty" you mean "factorial"?

Comment: There's really no way to avoid recursion in Prolog. Do you want to make it tail recursive to improve performance?

Comment: @DanielLyons You could of course cheat and try do do it with `foldl`, or you could really do it without recursion: use `repeat` and a global variable, or memoization.

Comment: 1) Show an attempt. 2) Be more specific by what you mean by "non rekursiv" (not proper English, btw). I could guess it could mean: a) proper tail-recursive; b) iteration using a `repeat` and global state; c) using memoization; d) something else I am missing.

Comment: @GrishaLevit Try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faculty).

Comment: Note the anomaly that `fakultaet(1+0, F)` succeeds, whereas `fakultaet(0+0,F)` fails.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it without a recursive call in your definition would be:

```
factorial(0, 1).
factorial(1, 1).
factorial(N, F) :-
    % the call to numlist/3 will fail if N < 2
    numlist(2, N, [X|Xs]), % [X|Xs] = [2,3,...,N]
    foldl(mult, Xs, X, P), % P = 2*3*...*N
    F is P.

mult(A, B, B*A).
```

This approach avoids recursion on syntactic level *in your definition*. Both `numlist/2` and `foldl/4` would most probably have a recursive definition, but you don't *have to* look at it. This probably falls into the "d) something else I am missing" category [from my comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731946/proloc-faculty-non-rekursiv#comment70666800_41731946).

Comment: Both of `numlist/2` and `foldl/4` are not ISO predicates though. Both would be easy to write with recursion though. ;)

Comment: @DanielLyons Sticking religiously to ISO predicates is really not going to get you very far if you want to write useful stuff in Prolog :( But yes, just look at the implementation of either from SWI-Prolog, which is both open source and not ISO-compliant.

Comment: @DanielLyons BTW, I am quite sure that this is _not_ the answer that OP is after. What OP is after I don't really know. For another undecipherable question, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41700196/1812457).

Comment: I know, I'm just being pedantic. This is close to how I would do it in Haskell: `fact n = product [1..n]`.

Answer (score -1):

if your Prolog has [global variables](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar), you can do

```
fakultaet(N,F) :-
    nb_setval(f,1),
    forall(between(2,N,I), (nb_getval(f,T), G is T*I, nb_setval(f,G))),
    nb_getval(f,F).
```

This particular usage of nb_setval/2, nb_getval/2 could be partially simulated with assert/1, retract/1, but the resulting program would be very, very inefficient