# specific sorting in PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog

I have to write a predicate `insort/2` which reduces any list (with possibly
duplicated elements) to a list in which each distinct element appears only once
and a specific order is used. For example,

```
? - insort([a,[a,a],[a,b],[b,a],[[a,b]],[d],c],X).
X = [a,c,[a],[d],[a,b],[[a,b]]]
yes
? - insort([[a,[a,b]],[a,[c,b]],[[a,b],a]], X).
X = [[a,[a,b]],[a,[b,c]]]
yes
? - insort([[a,b],[a,[a]],[a,b,c]],X).
X = [[a,b],[a,[a]],[a,b,c]]
yes
```

The order should first examine the total length of the list and the list with smaller total length is “smaller”. If total length is the
same then the natural order of terms in PROLOG should be adopted. But final solution cannot use SWI-Prolog built-in `sort/2` and `merge/3` predicates.

My work for now is like that:

```
rlen([],0). 
rlen(X,1).
rlen([Head|Tail],N):-rlen(Head,Q1),rlen(Tail,Q2),N is Q1+Q2. 

member(Head, [Head|Tail]).
member(X, [Head|Tail]) :- member(X,Tail).

remove_duplicates([],[]).

remove_duplicates([H | T], List) :-    
     member(H, T),
  remove_duplicates( T, List).

remove_duplicates([H | T], [H|T1]) :- 
  \+member(H, T),
  remove_duplicates( T, T1).


count(_,[],0).
count(X,[X],1).
count(X, [X|Y],N):- count(X,Y,W),N is W + 1.
count(Z,[X|Y],N):- count(Z,Y,N),X\=Z.

elsort([],[]).
elsort([A|B],C):-
  elsort(B,D),
  (is_list(A)->elsort(A, SA);SA=A),
  elsortx(SA,D,C).

elsortx(A,[X|B],[X|C]):-
order(X,A),
!,
elsortx(A,B,C).
elsortx(A,B,[A|B]).

order(X,Y) :- is_list(X), is_list(Y), length(X,A),length(Y,B),A<B.
order(A,A2):-
    A @< A2.
```

But still missing some things, I don't know how use here remove_duplicates,
and why `order([[a,b]],[a,b]).` throws true, should be false

Thanks for help, I really don't know how handle this

Comment: What have you done so far in attempts to debug? Have you tried `trace`?

Comment: This looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700196/how-to-write-predicate-convert-2-in-prolog